# Parsing an XML file in R

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file that I want to parse using R. I ran the code below to parse it to a data frame  and get the outputs below. In the data frame I am unable to obtain the datetime="2016-12-15T22:45:40.000Z". I am able to obtain 
cumulativeoperatinghours 1059.64 in the dataframe. I want to parse this date time field out of the XML document into a dataframe. Any ideas on how to do it?

```
     xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame("xamal.xml")
     xmlfile <- xmlParse("xamal.xml")
     rootnode <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
     rootsize <- xmlSize(rootnode)

     print(rootsize)
     [1] 103
     print(rootnode[[11]][[5]])
    <CumulativeOperatingHours datetime="2016-12-15T22:45:40.000Z">
    <Hour>1059.60</Hour>
    </CumulativeOperatingHours>
```

Below is the XML file I am trying to read into R. It's a long file so I need to read it into R as a file and create a dataframe in R including the attribute date and time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group xmlns="http://standards.is.com/is/151/-1" version="2" Time="2018-05-30T19:33:44.352Z">
   <Links>
      <rel>self</rel>
      <href>https://cloud.com/1</href>
   </Links>
   <Links>
      <rel>last</rel>
      <href>https://cloud.com/2</href>
   </Links>
   <Links>
      <rel>next</rel>
      <href>https://cloud.com/3</href>
   </Links>
   <Equip>
      <EquipHead>
         <Name>CAST</Name>
         <Model>1100</Model>
         <EquipmentID>Desk</EquipmentID>
         <SerialNumber>12312312</SerialNumber>
         <PIN>123123</PIN>
      </EquipHead>
      <Location datetime="2012-06-25T11:14:54.000Z">
         <Latitude>44.57</Latitude>
         <Longitude>-95.51</Longitude>
      </Location>
      <OperatingHours datetime="2012-03-01T17:42:37.000Z">
         <Hour>198.80</Hour>
      </OperatingHours>
   </Equip>
   <Equip>
      <EquipHead>
         <Name>Yuza</Name>
         <Model>L208</Model>
         <EquipmentID>4DW772GP</EquipmentID>
         <SerialNumber>4DW772GP</SerialNumber>
         <PIN>1DW772GPVJF</PIN>
      </EquipHead>
      <Location datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:46.000Z">
         <Latitude>47.518556</Latitude>
         <Longitude>-70.422444</Longitude>
      </Location>
      <IdleHours datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
         <Hour>33.74</Hour>
      </IdleHours>
      <OperatingHours datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:48.000Z">
         <Hour>72.35</Hour>
      </OperatingHours>
      <Distance datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
         <Odometer>kilometre</Odometer>
         <OdometerV>30.9</OdometerV>
      </Distance>
      <FuelUsed datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
         <FuelUnits>litre</FuelUnits>
         <Consumed>395</Consumed>
      </FuelUsed>
   </Equip>
   <Equip>
      <EquipHead>
         <OEMName>CALL</OEMName>
         <Model>562A</Model>
         <EquipmentID>1W2772G</EquipmentID>
         <SerialNumber>1TT772GPTE</SerialNumber>
         <PIN>1MM772GPTE</PIN>
      </EquipHead>
      <Location datetime="2018-05-30T07:00:17.000Z">
         <Latitude>22.809278</Latitude>
         <Longitude>-45.316417</Longitude>
      </Location>
      <IdleHours datetime="2018-05-24T20:37:03.000Z">
         <Hour>457.10</Hour>
      </IdleHours>
      <OperatingHours datetime="2018-05-30T18:25:18.000Z">
         <Hour>26.35</Hour>
      </OperatingHours>
      <Distance datetime="2018-05-23T13:26:37.000Z">
         <Units>kilometre</Units>
         <OdometerV>5075.6997</OdometerV>
      </Distance>
      <FuelUsed datetime="2018-05-24T20:37:03.000Z">
         <FuelUnits>litre</FuelUnits>
         <FuelConsumed>2548</FuelConsumed>
      </FuelUsed>
   </Equip>
</Group>
```

Comment: Try checkout out `XML::xmlAttrs()`. This function makes it easy grab the attributes of a xml elements (i.e., to grab the `datetime` attributes).

Comment: what would the code look like with the arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the undocumented, internal variable `XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame` and `cbind` it with documented, `xmlToDataFrame`:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse('/path/to/input.xml')
namespaces <- c(n="http://standards.is.com/is/151/-1")

xmldataframe <- cbind(xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//n:OperatingHours", namespaces)),
                      XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, "//n:OperatingHours", namespaces)))
xmldataframe 

#     Hour                 datetime
# 1 198.80 2012-03-01T17:42:37.000Z
# 2  72.35 2018-05-30T19:22:48.000Z
# 3  26.35 2018-05-30T18:25:18.000Z
```

Comment: I am getting the error below. This snipped is part of a long XML file                                                                      > xmldataframe <- cbind(xmlToDataFrame(xmlfile, nodes=getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//CumulativeOperatingHours")),
+                       XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xmlfile, "//CumulativeOperatingHours")))
Warning message:
In combineNamedVectors(lapply(doc, xmlAttrs), attrs, omit, ...) :
  no elements to combine across records

Comment: Please post a full XML (not snippet). Possibly *dateime* attribute is not on all *CumulativeOperatingHours* nodes. Here, `cbind` assumes lengths are equal.

Comment: I have posted more snippet

Comment: You should absolutely not add that XML to my answer but into your question.

Comment: @Parfait-I have posted in the right place for you to look it

Comment: Simply change the nodes since *CumulativeOperatingHours* does not exist. Use *OperatingHours* instead. See edit.

Comment: @Parfait- I am getting the error below. What could be the reason?       > xmldataframe <- cbind(xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//OperatingHours")),
+                       XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, "//OperatingHours")))
Warning message:
In combineNamedVectors(lapply(doc, xmlAttrs), attrs, omit, ...) :
  no elements to combine across records
> xmldataframe
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: even if i run x<-xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//OperatingHours")) by itself I get the below error                                      data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows                                                             It beats me what the error could be

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It woks. One last question I had was if the parent node Groups was modified as below this does not work. What is a solution to that?                                                                      <Group xmlns="http://standard.is.org" version="2" Time="2018-05-30T19:33:44.352Z">

Comment: Indeed. With that change, you now have a default namespace. Please post the **exact** XML so we can avoid this back and forth. Do note: your previous XML had many errors and was not a correct, well-formed XML with unclosed/misnamed/broken tags and would fail to be parsed into R. See the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50615590/revisions) I had to make.

Comment: I have added the attribute to Group node. Please see how this xml code can be parsed

Comment: Please see my edit, adding *namespace* arguments into the `getNodeSet` method.

Comment: @Parfait-Very elegant solution. Thanks!